# Where can I find my screenshots?

Tags: pc, forza-motorsport-6

I took some screenshots with the in-game Photo Mode in the Forza 6 Apex beta, but I can't find them anywhere.

Are the screenshots available anywhere in a readable format or are they obfuscated and hidden by the windows store drm?

Comment: They wouldn't be hidden; try looking in your photos folder; if it's not in there try emailing the creator

Comment: They are not in my photos or documents folders, those were the first places I checked.

Comment: Are they in some kind of game menu?

Comment: Yes, they are available in `Driver Record > Forza Gallery`. There's no option to save them to a location on HDD, so either they are already saved as viewable files or they are encrypted. I just want a confirmation of either of the possibilities, as I can't seem to find the photos in a viewable format.